# Access to several containers in the class

Tags: c++, oop, containers

Suppose there is a class with several (e.g. 2) containers as private members. Would that be good to have different kinds of `begin()` (or `at()`) member functions to access iterator (or element) of the corresponding container?

Here is the small example:

```
class Example
{
private:
    std::vector<double> A;
    std::vector<double> B;
public:
    double& A(std::size_t index) { return A.at(index); }
    double& B(std::size_t index) { return B.at(index); }
};
```

I need to have such kind of access because there is one class that asks for the values in container A and there is also another class asking for the contents of B. In general class `Example` might have more than two containers.

Is that a good idea or there is better solution?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is some additional information: container `A` Holds always some parameters that will be passed to different functions, container `B` holds the values return from the function that has been passed container `A` as an argument. And the rest of possible containers will hold different constraints on the values that can be stored in `A`

Answer (score 1):

Does anything outside of the class care about the contents of these vectors? If not, create a member function to take a function pointer and use it with the vectors. Then you don't need to expose the vectors. Fully exposing internal objects with get functions defeats the point of making them private.

Answer (score 0):

If there might be more, it seems like you actually have some kind of "list" of containers. Almost like your naming scheme `A`, `B`, ... is just enumerating them, which is always a sign you should be using some sort of container. Then maybe you actually want a container of `std::vector`s? If it's a fixed amount, something like:

```
std::array<std::vector<double>, N> containers;
```

If it's not fixed, then:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> containers;
```

Then you could have a single function that asks for the index of the container and then an index within that container:

```
double& get(std::size_t container, std::size_t element) {
  return containers[container][element];
}
```

Comment: In my case an element in `B` Is a result returned from some function that takes as a parameter container `A`.

Comment: @Nikita That would still work. I assume if you have more than just `A` and `B`, this relationship can be between any of them arbitrarily? That is, `D` might have elements from a function that takes `B`? If so, this works nicely.

Comment: Hmm, `D` can have different restrictions on the elements in `A`

Comment: @Nikita You seem to have some complex constraints that you didn't tell us about in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need such accessors. You might consider putting **const** keyword on the returned value if elements doesn't have to be modified

```
const double& getA(std::size_t index) { return A.at(index); }
```

Comment: Sometimes the value has to be modified and sometimes does not, so I can actually put both versions

Comment: yes, this is good to have both so you can then get modifiable or non-modifiable element from the container

Comment: You cannot avoid this if you need access, right? Is this good? It is unavoidable.

Comment: It suggests a design problem.